# Careers 2.0 completeness total incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When I browse to my profile the right-hand sidebar states that my completeness score is 200/210. However, when I click the "View completeness report" link in the sidebar the page shows that I have a "Grand Total: 210 / 210". As well, the sidebar still contains the incorrect value.

Comment: @max - Planning to implement this bug? ;)

Comment: @Lix no, planning to fix it! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took as a while, but this should now be fixed.